# App takes too long to load in production

Tags: javascript, express, heroku, angular, systemjs

I have pushed my angular 2 app on heroku but it takes too long to load.

is there a way to bundle everything up because right now i have this in my index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <base href="/">
    <title>Angular 2 Arc</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <ng2-app>Loading...</ng2-app>
  <!-- Load Angular 2 Core libraries -->
  <script src="es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
  <script src="angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
  <script src="systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
  <script src="rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
  <script src="angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
  <script src="angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
  <script src="angular2/bundles/http.js"></script>
  <!-- Load Bootstrap and Jquery -->
  <script src="lib/jquery/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/github-fork-ribbon-css/0.2.0/gh-fork-ribbon.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/app.css">
  <!-- Configure SystemJS -->
  <script>
      System.config({
          defaultJSExtensions: true,
          packages: {
              boot: {
                  format: 'register',
                  defaultExtension: 'js'
              }
          }
      });
      System.import('js/boot')
              .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My setup is express server and system JS.

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var fs = require("fs");

// initialize express
var app = express();

// declare build and node_module paths

app.use(express.static("./build"));
app.use(express.static("./node_modules/"));

// parse request body
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

var body;
// route to send json data from angular 2
app.post('/export', function(req, res){
  body = req.body;
  res.json("Got the data!");

  fs.writeFile('parameters.json', JSON.stringify({body}, null, 4), function (err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    console.log('Data json file created!');
  });
});


// start server
app.listen(process.env.PORT || "3001", function(){
  console.log("Express server running on localhost:3001");
});
```

Comment: Take a look at systemjs builder; anything loaded via systemjs can be bundled into a self executing script (containing all systemjs dependencies in addition to your own).

Comment: You can take a look at these two popular seeds using webpack and systemjs respectively : [angular2-webpack-starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter), [angular2-seed](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed).

Answer (score 1):

If its the free heroku tier its probably because its sleeping when you request it?

You can minify and concatenate your js files to decrease load times.

Here is a guide on how to do that with gulp tasks:
https://caveofcode.com/2016/03/gulp-tasks-for-minification-and-concatenation-of-dependencies-in-angularjs/

Comment: what seems to take a lot of time is system.src.js for some reason it makes more than 500 requests.

Comment: Wow thats alot. I have only used the .net bundles and gulp tasks for this kinda stuff. Hope you will get it sorted out!